# how to handle the error with facebook c# sdk : (OAuthException) Error validating access token: Session has expired

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, session-cookies, unix-timestamp

(end of the title) at unix time 1312318800. The current unix time is 1312319142.

I'm stuck with this error when trying to get the friends of a user after some time.
I think that I need to catch that and go back to the login page but even with that I think that the accesstoken is not renewed by the new one by the sdk.
My app is a facebook app working in an iframe and I do not want to ask for an offline access authorization to work around the issue.
Any help will be appreciated.

BR,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

Double check your server time. Make sure that it's synchronized with the correct world time according to the set time-zone